# Form submit doesn't work for the second time, if nothing was changed

Tags: submit

Form submit doesn't work for the second time, if nothing was changed. It is not possible to make a search in a little while with the same filters. I've added a random number in the URL to resolve this. But this is bad for google analitics, now they notice them as different links.

Comment: Sharing the code would help us to answer!

Comment: Please look at here. http://en.kub.az/

Comment: try to click Find button second time without changing the filters

Comment: it looks like a browser security

Comment: can you share the code of the form ?

Comment: TharinduLucky, I found the solution, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. The problem was due to the anchor in the form action:

```
<form action="/search#anchor">
...
```

This is the corrected form action

```
<form action="/search">
```

Thanks to all.